# Php file_get_contents to much echo'd

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Another php related question
I am using file_get_contents to get information from a website (weather).
My code does what it is suppose to do.
How ever the website does not have a ID or class name at the part i want to get. so i use the (div) class from which it is in.

The div i want to get:

```
<div class="page-title">
  <H1>
   <label class> Het is vandaag vrij zonnig in </label>
   <label> Los Angeles</label>
   <script> ... bla bla bla</script>
```

What i get:

> Het is vandaag vrij zonnig in Los Angeles { "ScriptUrl":"http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=weeronline", "addthis_config": { "pubid":"weeronline", "ui_language":"nl", "data_ga_property":"UA-3047268-1", "data_track_clickback":"true", "data_ga_social":"true" } }

So thats ok, but i only want the "het is vandaag vrij zonnig in Los Angeles"  printed.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the result is always going to be in that format, you could do

```
echo substr($string, 0, strpos($string, "{"));
```

(assuming `$string` is the content you gave above)

Comment: first of all, what a fast comment! thank you.
Your solution however gave me everything on the right side of the "{"
instead of the left side!
how to change this?

Comment: yes, i was sure, but i must have typed something wrong!
 because it works now!

Thank you Patrick Q and Dan H for your solutions which, for the readers of this same problem Works!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want that string?  Try using substr?

EDIT: url: https://www.php.net/substr

Comment: Yes i want that string.
using substring works
but what if they change 1 parameter? cuz i have this coded now:
echo substr($div->nodeValue,0,-303);

Comment: That's just life when it comes to parsing other people's websites for content -- been there, done that.  The only thing left to do with make your finding logic to be more robust, but expect that to change anyway (same with the url, etc, everything is a wild card and not reliable).  In short, all you can do is keep current on their site, or maybe ask them directly if they can provide a data feed for you that would not change.

Answer (score 0):

`echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents...)`